# Get publish permission for Facebook app for iOS with -openWithBehavior:completionHandler:

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In my application I need user to sign in to Facebook, get friend list in my table view and Post on feeds, but I don't want to redirect the user anywhere. so I used -openWithBehavior:completionHandler: ... Here is my code.

```
-(IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender {
[self deleteCookies];
// get the app delegate so that we can access the session property
DLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

// this button's job is to flip-flop the session from open to closed
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    // if a user logs out explicitly, we delete any cached token information, and next
    // time they run the applicaiton they will be presented with log in UX again; most
    // users will simply close the app or switch away, without logging out; this will
    // cause the implicit cached-token login to occur on next launch of the application
    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

} else {
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        [self updateView];
    }

    // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
    [appDelegate.session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        switch (status) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                // call the legacy session delegate
                //Now the session is open do corresponding UI changes
            {
                FBCacheDescriptor *cacheDescriptor = [FBFriendPickerViewController cacheDescriptor];
                [cacheDescriptor prefetchAndCacheForSession:session];
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"publish_actions", nil] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:nil];
            }
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            { // prefer to keep decls near to their use                    
                // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                // call the legacy session delegate if needed
                //[[delegate facebook] fbDialogNotLogin:userDidCancel];
            }
                break;
                // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class
            default:
                break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
        }
        [self updateView];
    }];
}
}
```

The user is successfully signed in and I can retrieve the friend list by using FQL. The problem is while posting to feeds. I know I need to get publish permissions to do it. But when I uses the following code to post...

```
- (IBAction)postAction:(id)sender {
DLAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
    NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
                                       @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
                                       @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
                                       @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                       @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
                                       nil];
    if ([_postText.text length]>0) {
        [postParams setObject:[_postText text] forKey:@"message"];
    }
    if (([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
          indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) ||
        ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
          indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound)) {

        // No permissions found in session, ask for it
        [FBSession.activeSession
         reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:
         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"publish_actions",nil]
         defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 // If permissions granted, publish the story
                 [self publishStory:postParams];
             }
         }];
    } else {
        // If permissions present, publish the story
        [self publishStory:postParams];
    }
}    
}

-(void)publishStory:(NSDictionary *)postParams {
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:
                             @"me/feed" parameters:postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {
         //Tell the user that it worked.
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Shared:"
                                                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sucessfully posted to your wall."]
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
         alertView.tag = 101;
         [alertView show];
     }
     else {
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error:"
                                                             message:error.localizedDescription
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alertView show];
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
     }
 }
 ];    
}
```

This code redirects the user to Safari or Facebook App. Which I don't want to happen.

Definitely I need to get publish permissions while logging in. the question is HOW?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set FBSessionLoginBehavior, to change it the only way is to use:

```
[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                        FBSessionState status,
                        NSError *error) {
        // Respond to session state changes, 
        // ex: updating the view
    }];
```

I see you use `FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView`, so to get what you want you have to choose from this enum:

```
typedef enum {
/*! Attempt Facebook Login, ask user for credentials if necessary */
FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView      = 0,
/*! Attempt Facebook Login, no direct request for credentials will be made */
FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView    = 1,
/*! Only attempt WebView Login; ask user for credentials */
FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView             = 2,
/*! Attempt Facebook Login, prefering system account and falling back to fast app switch if necessary */
FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent  = 3,
} FBSessionLoginBehavior;
```

Now to solve this "Definitely I need to get publish permissions while logging in. the question is HOW?" you may `- (id)initWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions;` your `Session` :

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"];
appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
```